# Position HTML popover element relative to parent for dropdown

Tags: html

I'm experimenting with the new [Popover API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API) and trying to make a dropdown with it.

I have a button to open my dropdown menu, the dropdown menu itself, and I'm struggling to position my dropdown menu correctly. I want to place it directly below the button. I've tried `position: absolute` on my dropdown and `position: relative` on a parent div, but it does not seem to help.

```html
  Hello world

  <div style="position: relative">
    <button popovertarget="dropdown">Open Dropdown</button>
    <div popover id="dropdown" style="position: absolute; top: 20px">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu Item 1</li>
        <li>Menu Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, the popover appears in the center of the screen. Is it possible to position a `popover` relative to another element?

Comment: If you mean how to get rid of the left text indent, then you will need `padding-left`. To reduce the gap between the button and the list items use `margin-top`. So, as it's currently written in the snippet, change `<ul>` to `<ul style="margin-top: 0; padding-left: 15px;">`. You may need to adjust values for `margin` and `padding-left` when using a different font, font-size, etc.

Comment: I want the popover to appear immediately under the button. Here's a screenshot description: https://imgur.com/zxQ3zmY

Answer (score 1):

As the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API/Using) said

```
To override the default styles and get the popover to appear somewhere else on your viewport, you would need to override the above styles with something like

...
inset: unset;
...
```

So your code should be

```
  Hello world

<div>
    <button popovertarget="dropdown">Open Dropdown</button>
    <div popover id="dropdown" style="inset: unset">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu Item 1</li>
        <li>Menu Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can refer to their [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API/Using#nested_popovers) for more information.

Comment: Thanks - that offers more control. But I still can't seem to position the popover relative to the parent div like I would a non-popover element.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue. The problem is that HTML5 popovers and dialogs are in a different stacking context, in the [top layer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Top_layer).

Currently there is no cross-browser way to anchor the positioning to an specific element. There is a new [CSS property called `overlay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overlay#browser_compatibility), which is only supported in Chrome-based browsers,

but I found one trick (keeping all benefits of the native popover) by using a sibling container and a sibling CSS selector:

```css
.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

[popover] {
  inset: unset;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;

  overlay: none; /* this alone would do the trick, but its not supported yet in all major browsers*/
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: #164780;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

[popover]:popover-open + .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button popovertarget="empty-popover">Open Menu</button>
  <div id="empty-popover" popover></div>
  <div class="menu">
    Profile<br />
    Settings<br />
    Logout<br />
  </div>
<div>
```